# Facebook login fails on website with SSL

Tags: php, facebook, ssl, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

We're building a web app in PHP. We've set up SSL certificate and right after that the FB login stopped working. When the script tries to get user ID, exception is thrown

> An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

I'm 100% positive the SSL is the problem because it works fine on my localhost and it also worked on the production before setting up the SSL.

We're using Facebook PHP SDK. Here is the first part (getting login url)

```
$facebook = new Facebook([
    "appId" => "APP_ID",
    "secret" => "SECRET"
]);

$permissions = ["email", "user_birthday", "publish_stream", "offline_access"];
$loginURL = $facebook->getLoginUrl([
    "scope" => join(",", $permissions),
    "redirect_uri" => "REDIRECT_URI"
]);
// redirect to $loginURL
```

And here's the callback

```
$facebook = new Facebook([
    "appId" => "APP_ID",
    "secret" => "SECRET"
]);

$userID = $facebook->getUser();
$token  = $_GET['code'];

if(isset($userID) && isset($token)) {
    // ... some cool stuff
} else {
    // error, something happened
}
```

Thanx for help

EDIT: I was getting the error because I was trying to get details about user by the `$userID`. Problem was, the `$userID` is always 0 so no wonder I got error. Somehow I can't get user's ID on the website with SSL...

Comment: how about error logs?

Comment: You are aware that the GET parameter `code` is _not_ the access token, right? (Your line `$token  = $_GET['code'];` makes me assume that you might be trying to use that value as access token for API calls, which of course would be wrong.)

Comment: I don't use it as access token. I don't use access token anywhere, this is complete code for the callback and it's basicaly taken from documentation (and it works on not-SLL sites)

Comment: @MichalArtazov Are all endpoints and calls going through SSL. If you are swapping between http: and https: your session will be lost. Alternatively can you use the javascript flow? I prefer it to the server implementations.

Comment: @Matthew.Lothian yeah it should - first it redirects you to Facebook which is https, then it redirects you to callback which is https too (I checked it) and then the error happens

Comment: @Matthew.Lothian I could try the JS flow but I'd rather not if there're other options...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK in the end I found the cause of my problems and it was realy stupid (like almost always, right?). When I was building the callback URL that is sent as an argument to the FB login page, I was getting the base url with a method from the framework I use. For some reason it gave me `domain.com:443/` instead of `domain.com/`. After I fixed it, it suddenly works.

Answer (score 0):

In mu case it was the WWW that was missing from the redirect URL. SSL cert was working only with it